# Who is this [publisher]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/publisher) have questions with very different definitions of "publisher":

- [Swift Publisher](https://www.swiftpublisher.com/):

  - *[How to implement a Publisher extension, It drops elements until the asynchronous task associated with each element is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77730117)*
  - *[Timer.publish on non main Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77375691)*
  - *[How to run async function (URLSession) inside a Publisher .onReceive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77080477)*
  - *[My subscriber cannot receive subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76982597)*
- [Microsoft Publisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Publisher):

  - *[Fetch the publisher's prefix in dynamics 365 plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77854482)*
  - *[How do I set the row height to be the same for all rows in a Publisher 2010 table? (With answer!)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77258247)*
  - *[Why VBA macro does not export document to PDF with correct page size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77228224)*
- [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/):

  - *[Publisher - Consument (publisher as controller) rabbitmq and redis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77841848)*
  - *[RabbitMQ ConfirmChannel publish method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77255643)*
- Something else:

  - *[Why is the "Issued to" and "Issued by" fields are numbers instead of my name? in Visual Studio when signing a program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77553532)*
  - *[Is there a way to cache responses using Mono from a WebClient call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76901098)*

...the list goes on.

### Criteria

1. > Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   No. See the list above.
2. > Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Maybe. I know nothing about any of those topics, but some of the questions do have code.
3. > Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   Probably no.
4. > Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   Somewhat? In programming context a "publisher" is normally understood as a program that publishes, but that's about it.

Comment: Did your research find any of those usages to be heavy enough to deserve its own disambiguating tag?

Comment: @MarkRansom To be honest, I'm not even sure if my categorization above is correct. [A query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpublisher%5D+and+%5Bswift%5D) for `[publisher] and [swift]` returns 19 questions, but I'm not a SDE to tell that they are all about the same app.

Comment: The "`publisher`" referenced in the above "Swift Publisher" section is referring to the `publisher` protocol in an iOS state management library called Combine that is used with the Swift programming language, not an application called "Swift Publisher". I'd suggest that should this tag get disambiguated `[combine-publisher]` would be accurate. Other iOS developers can chime in. Combine is the native state management library written by Apple and every iOS developer should know what it is. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher

Comment: Note that https://stackoverflow.com/q/77854482/7296893 is not about Microsoft Publisher. This tag certainly deserves disambiguation, but we should do so carefully.